# Seeking low-cost level shift solution

Tags: level-shifting

I need to interface two high-voltage MOSFETs to a PIC microcontroller.  This normally easily done simply using a MOSFET or bipolar transistor as an inverter.  However, my added constraint is that the high-voltage MOSFETs must be held OFF while the controller is in reset or otherwise not capable of maintaining a logic 1 on the output pin.

I could easily add an appropriate pull-up resistor to the PIC pin but power consumption is also a concern.

My favorite level shifter is a simple cascode circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGawKk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can anyone suggest anything less expensive in low to medium quantities (250 to 1000 pcs)?

Comment: Did you consider a gate driver chip?

Comment: Why not just add a diode from the gate of M2 to the reset line? Without a pull-down though...no guarantees that if 5V supply shuts down that M2 will shut off.

Comment: Dwayne, 150 V BJTs like the 2N5401 and 2N5550 are less than 3 cents each, if you keep an eye out. But I do buy in 2000 qty, when I buy. (I get PN2222A for about 0.4 cents each -- cheaper still.) Since I just cannot seem to find any mosfets near those prices in those qtys, perhaps you could consider using a BJT for at least the cascoded active device? (Though I think your RBn pin should actually be at the ground end of your emitter resistor or else you'd operate the BJT base with the pin, instead.) This hybrid situation should allow you to select your power mosfet as before.

Comment: @jonk: the MOSFET M1 is rated at 600V. My preference would be to find a logic-level FET with that voltage rating but nothing inexpensive is available. But I will see if I can work a BJT in as the level shifter and still keep the current at a minimum.

Comment: @DwayneReid Did I somehow miss out on seeing 600 V mentioned? (NPNs can be had there, of course. But I hadn't understood your need when you wrote. No idea that you had a rail voltage that high.)

Comment: I mentioned "high-voltage MOSFETs" but did not specify the voltage magnitude. These MOSFETs are being used to switch load resistors. Speed is not critical - the MOSFETs turn on or off only at system power application. Maximum voltage being switched is 450 Vdc. I should also mention that IRF530 isn't the FET I'm using - that's just the default that the schematic editor used.